# Should I split a DbContext with multiple DbSets with hundreds of thousands of records in each of them?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

**My question: what determines the speed(performance) of calling DbContext.SaveChanges() method? And is it a bad practice to put all the DbSets in a single DbContext?**

I have a c#/WPF/MS SQL Server/Entity Framework Core project, which is actually for my company's wholesale business.

I implemented a single DbContext which contains dozens of DbSet's, each of which, of course, represents a table in the database. There are about 10 major tables representing orders, order details, customers, products, etc, and each of the major DbSet/tables contains about 50,000 to 150,000 records in it. The problem is when DbContext.SaveChanges method is called, it takes over 9,000ms(9 sec) to execute! I put ALL of the DbSets in the same DbContext. Is this a bad habit and the cause for slow speed?

For a test, I created a separate DbContext and put only one DbSet in it. The DbSet has about 100,000 records, but calling SaveChanges for that took about 500ms, which was a significant improvement.

Given my situation, what is the best practice for database performances? Please help.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(DbConn.GetConnStr());
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }     // This has 100k+ records.
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }     // This has 150k+ records.
        public DbSet<Ship> Ships { get; set; }               // 100k+ records
        public DbSet<ShipDetail> ShipDetails { get; set; }   // 150k+ records
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }     // 100k records
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }       // 10k+ records
        public DbSet<ProductStock> ProductStocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PriceType> PriceTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Carrier> Carriers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Import> Imports { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ImportDetail> ImportDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The number of DbSets doesn't matter. The context's lifetime and the amount of data you load into it do. Maybe you should give some more detail on those metrics.

Comment: I create an instance of DbContext at the startup and then pass it across all classes and objects. I use it for the duration of the application. Would this be the reason why it's slow?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Read this: [The DbContext lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/).  The life time of a DbContext should be very short.

Answer (score 1):

No, quite the opposite. You should encapsulate one database per dbContext extended class in your app. If it is just one db ( or rather one schema ) then you should not split the class at all.

Instead make a `partial` class and define different dbSets within domain-like-files that form up a concrete class.

The speed is based on the changes made x items loaded ( rly abstract... ).
The more changes, the more the rows that you are affecting/loading, the harder stuff get.

Biggest hit for you would be the sql updates. When you want to manage very big datasets, skip loading them into memory at all. Work with .FromSqlRaw and do everything at the db level returning the minimum that you need.
For example mass updates is a great case for this.

Also care for the case that you are loading uneeded objects ( relations that you are not using )

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Gert Arnold, rantri, and MKougiouris for your replies and comments. All of you are dead right. Here's what I've figured. As all of you mentioned, the problem was not the fact that a single DbContext has all tables in it. The problem was that I was using and passing around a single "instance" of my DbContext across multiple operations throughout the lifetime of running the appplication. This should NEVER be done with a DbContext.

I figured that a DbContext is supposed to be instantiated for a single unit-of-work or a single operation and then dispose the instance as soon as the operation is over. I was reading ALL of the DataSets into the DbContext and querying as much as possible with the single DbContext instance. This is a guarantee for slow performance.

I said it took 9 seconds(9,000ms) to persist changes to the DB by calling SaveChanges. Now it takes 250ms(0.25 sec) to get the same job done. Hope my comment helps for anyone with the same issue.